# MLE method for a statistical model with two random variables

Tags: maximum-likelihood, references

Suppose for fixed $t>0$ we have two discrete random variables $X_t$ and $X_{t+1}$ where $X_t$ takes on $11$ values 
$$
X_t\in\{0,1,2,\cdots, 10\}.
$$
Also, we have
$$
P(X_{t+1}=X_t)=1-\lambda,\quad P(X_{t+1}=\min\{X_t+1,10\})=\lambda. 
$$
What is the ML estimator for $\lambda$?

---

The question is motivated by a model  about bus engine replacement in microeconometrics. I have searched along [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) Wikipedia article and [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture2.pdf) lecture note. But I don't see how to do it since two random variables are involved. Could anyone come up with a theoretical reference for such an issue (MLE method for a statistical model with two random variables)? (Or this could be trivially reduced to the one-variable case?)

Comment: Do you just have two random variables or several consisting of the complete histories of more than one bus engine with the values of $X_1, X_2,..., X_t$ ?  That would also mean that we would assume that $t$ also takes on the discrete values $1, 2, 3, ..., t$ ?  And does $X_1=0$ with probability 1 ?

Comment: I'm now focusing on the case that $t$ is fixed. Thus there are only two random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer.

I wonder if you meant to give conditional probabilities such that $P(X_{n+1}=x_n | X_n = x_n)=1-\lambda$ and 
$P(X_{n+1}=\min{(x_t+1,10)}|X_n=x_n)=\lambda$ with $P(X_1=0)=1$.

That way the likelihood of an observed history with $t=6$ of 0 0 1 1 2 3 would be $(1-\lambda)^2 \lambda^3$ with the maximum likelihood estimator being 3/5.

In general with an arbitrary value of $t$ and $m$ occurrences where there was a change
from $X_i$ to $X_{i+1}$ the likelihood would be $(1-\lambda)^{t-m-1} \lambda^m$, the maximum
likelihood estimator of $\lambda$ would be $m/(t-1)$ (except when $X_t=10$ as then $X_{t+1}$ must also equal 10
resulting in no information about $\lambda$).

But if you only know say two values $X_5$ and $X_6$, then you only have a sample size of 1 and
the maximum likelihood estimator of $\lambda$ is 1 if $x_6 > x_5$ and 0 otherwise (unless $x_5=10$ when means that $x_6$ also equals 10 with probability 1 and for that case there is no information about $\lambda$).

Alternatively, if you have $n$ multiple sets of $X_t$ and $X_{t+1}$ 
(where $X_t < 10$ and if you can assume independence among the sets),then you simply have a binomial distribution 
and the maximum likelihood estimator is simply the number of observations of increases (m) divided
by n.

I still think you need to give more specifics.